# Creating a t2 instance with CreditSpecification in Cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to launch an AWS EC2 instance using the t2 unlimited burst cpu option in CloudFormation:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  EC2I1U4EQ:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-403e2524
      InstanceType: t2.small
      CreditSpecification:
        - CpuCredits: unlimited
```

But during the create process I get the error:

> Value of property CreditSpecification must be an object

I cannot find any examples of how to form the CreditSpecification yaml statement.

Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[According to the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreditSpecificationRequest.html), it's `- CPUCredits: unlimited`, you're lacking 2 capital letters

Comment: Thanks that would explain it!!

Comment: I like that nowhere in the doc it specifies what valid values are :) "unlimited" works though

Comment: @Claude, true! I must have mixed up my documentation links. This is the good one -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_CreditSpecificationRequest.html. I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! It actually seems like an oversight that the page you originally linked to doesn’t have this info (it’s also where you go when coming from CloudFormation EC2:Instance), with nowhere to learn the valid values. Happy to have the link now!

Comment: As rule of thumb, the "API" documentation is always more detailed and up to date than the one of CloudFormation. Just a thing to keep in mind when you see something lacking from the CF doc.

Answer (score 3):

Just to add to Laurent's answer,

*"Value of property CreditSpecification must be an object"* is occurred due to an error in the yaml code. If you use CpuCredits instead od CPUCredits, it'll throw an *"Unsupported/unknown property error"*.

Fix for your issue however is simple.

```
CreditSpecification:
  CPUCredits: unlimited
```